# Two call two pages in ajax in a single call using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My code calls ajax of single page and fetch result from that...

```
    ajax_data='ajax_mode=yes&data_id='+data1;
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "sample.php",
       data: ajax_data,
       dataType: "html",
       success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
       }
    });
```

***Question:*** I need to call multiple ajax pages in a single call (i.e within $.ajax)
and fetch result of appropriate pages

Comment: I would think that this needs to be in two separate calls (though I am prepared to be corrected!). Why can you not make to sequential ajax calls? Of course, the calls may return at different times.

Comment: I need to trigger an event once both call of ajax returns some data. in single function i want to call multiple ajax

Comment: you can't do this in a single call, it simply doesn't work this way.  You need to make changes server-side to get a single AJAX call (that returns all the data you want).

Comment: Thank u. I make changes in my server side pg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redesign your server side processes to return two sets of data, organized in a way that you can separate them out easily (e.g. by presenting the data as JSON).